# Ansible. override single dictionary key

Tags: python, yaml, ansible

I am using ansible to manage configuration as for production, as well as for vagrant box.
I have file with default values: **group_vars/all**.

```
---
env: prod
wwwuser: www-data

db:
    root_pwd: root_pwd
    pdo_driver: pdo_mysql
    host: localhost
    name: test
    user: test
    pwd: test
    charset: utf8

domain: somedomain
projectdir: /var/www/application
webrootdir: "{{ projectdir }}/web"
```

In **host_vars/vagrantbox** I want tohave something like:

```
db:
    root_pwd: super_easy_password
```

But this one is overriding completely db dictrionary, while I want to override single key.
How to achieve that?

*UPDATE 1*
Just checked with ansible.cfg:

```
[defaults]
host_key_checking=false
hash_behaviour=merge
```

**groups_vars/all**

```
db:
    root_pwd: some_strong_pwd
    pdo_driver: pdo_mysql
    host: localhost
    name: dbname
    user: dbuser
    pwd: some password
    charset: utf8
```

**host_vars/vagrantbox**

```
db:
    root_pwd: root
```

I am getting following error:

```
One or more undefined variables: 'dict object' has no attribute 'name'
```

What I do wrong?

Answer (score 32):

By default, Ansible overrides variables at the first level. If you want to be able to merge dictionaries, you have to change your `ansible.cfg` file and set :

```
hash_behaviour=merge
```

(the default value being `replace`).

Note that the Ansible team [does not recommend this](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#default-hash-behaviour).
I guess this is a real dividing setting between users. A kind of decision that is done once for all : when you start using this feature, you can not go back, and you probably can not share your playbook with `replace`-type people.

However, you can still benefit from the playbooks out there (I don't hink playbooks use `replace` behaviour as a "feature"). It's like having an AB blood type, being an universal receiver... but since the magic usually happens at variable resolution, not inside tasks or templates, I think it is often possible to share your roles without any changes.

If you need to override a single key from, let's say, role parameters, you'll have to pass parameters in some convoluted way.

For instance, to override `post_max_size` and `upload_max_size` keys in a `php5` dictionnary for a specific role, you'll have to do it this way :

```
- { role: php5-fpm, php5: { post_max_size: 40M,
                            upload_max_filesize: 20M }}
```

This being said, I use `merge` behaviour since the beginning, and I'm pretty happy with it. It is very handy to keep variables organised.

Comment: please check comment.

Comment: could you add `- debug: var=db` at the top of your playbook ? Also, check that your ansible.cfg is in the right place (http://docs.ansible.com/intro_configuration.html) and post your ansible version.

Comment: See this thread for more of an insight as to why it's seen as "bad practise": https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ansible-project/1f8Y1JCkwvI

TLDR: It encourages complicated behaviour, which the ansible creators see as a bad thing.

Comment: I suppose everybody sees complicated behaviours as a BadThing™. But saying "using hashes is more complicated than plain vars" is really subjective. I personnally don't think using hashes is complicated or yields complicated behaviours. Again, you can group your configurations, and it makes things much more readable in the end when you have complex setups, and have an interesting "scoping" side effect. It has one *BIG* downside though : you can not reuse some hash key value as another value for a key in the same hash (which can really be annoying !)

Comment: I don't understand the downside, care to elaborate? You would never be able to use the same key twice in the same hash..

Comment: @grasshopper: for instance, you can not define :
foo.bar: 5 and in the same dict foo.baz: {{ foo.bar }} (sorry, it is not possible to put code in comments; you have to imagine this 'yaml-style'.

Comment: ah, okay.  Thanks for clarifying. I can't see a usecase where I'd do that however.

Comment: Surely it'd make sense to add an operator to make explicit merging possible only where desired? Having this as some kind of global magic is just bizarre.

Comment: This hash merging behavior is default in Chef via the [`Chef::Mash`](https://github.com/chef/chef/blob/master/lib/chef/mash.rb) class and [`Chef::Mixin::DeepMerge`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/opscode/chef/Chef/Mixin/DeepMerge).  There are precedence rules which give fairly straightforward override ordering for attributes from multiple locations & override levels.  From a pure Object-Oriented perspective, when dealing with multiple cookbooks it is very useful to have this deep-merge behavior because it allows one to follow a pattern of overriding a specific hash key in a meaningful place.

Comment: The one example I'd give is: a wrapper cookbook (inheriting attributes from another "base-class" cookbook), is able to override a specific hash key deep within the node's attribute hash structure, in order to provide a specific behavior or configuration.  This can be metaphorically likened to the [Method Overriding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_overriding) pattern of a more specific class (which [inherits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_(object-oriented_programming)) from a Base Class) overriding a method of the Base Class in order to provide more specific behavior

Comment: I understand the perspective of this seeming complicated to those unfamiliar with OOP, but it allows for a more elegant, specific, declarative and re-usable expression of a server's configuration via cookbooks or roles which follow the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).  It allows one to simply wrap & inherit attributes / vars from another role / cookbook and override just the things you need to provide a more concise description of the resources to be configured / converged.  However, this comes with the complexity of precedence.

Comment: one could probably make the same arguments about CSS inheritance, or any OOP inheritance hierarchy concept.

Answer (score 17):

Starting with Ansible 2.0, you can use the Jinja2 `combine` filter to merge YAML hashes/dictionaries without having to set `hash_behavior=merge` at a global level in your `ansible.cfg` file.

Relevant docs: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#sts=Combining%20hashes/dictionaries%C2%B6

Comment: For Ansible <2.0 one can use `include_vars_merged`: https://gist.github.com/udondan/b730206056a018cf9838

Comment: Would you happen to know how to apply `combine` to a role parameter as http://stackoverflow.com/a/25131711/107158 describes?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41247778/in-ansible-how-can-i-combine-a-default-dictionary-in-a-role-with-a-dictionary-p addresses this question.

Answer (score 9):

The best way I have found is to use variables as the value of the dictionary item, and override that.  I find this allows simple and powerful variable precedence with regards to ansible's order of variable

#### role/parent/defaults/main.yml

```
---
root_pw_value: ParentPassword

parent_dict:
  - root_pw: "{{ root_pw_value }}"
```

#### role/child/defaults/main.yml

Note: `role/child/meta/main.yml` contains `dependencies: - { role: parent }`

```
---
root_pw_value: ChildPassword
```

#### play-me.yml

```
---
  - hosts: all
    roles:
      - child
```

#### roles/parent/tasks/main.yml & roles/child/tasks/main.yml

```
- debug: var=parent_dict
```

Run `ansible -i localhost, --connection="local" play-me.yml` and you get the following output:

```
PLAY [all] ******************************************************************** 

GATHERING FACTS *************************************************************** 
ok: [localhost]

TASK: [parent | debug var=parent_dict] **************************************** 
ok: [localhost] => {
    "var": {
        "parent_dict": [
            {
                "root_pw": "ParentPassword"
            }
        ]
    }
}

TASK: [child | debug var=parent_dict] ***************************************** 
ok: [localhost] => {
    "var": {
        "parent_dict": [
            {
                "root_pw": "ChildPassword"
            }
        ]
    }
}

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************** 
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

And these are defaults.  If you specify `root_pw_value` at more specific levels of precedence, such as inventory group/host variables, role variables, extra_vars on the command line, or anything from the precedence order[0] you'll get those.

[0] http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable

Answer (score -1):

Just tried with ansible 1.9.3 and it works fine. Not sure but it seems you just have a typo within name of `group_vars` directory (not `groups_vars`).