# merging dictionaries in ansible

Tags: python, dictionary, merge, ansible

I'm currently building a role for installing PHP using ansible, and I'm having some difficulty merging dictionaries. I've tried several ways to do so, but I can't get it to work like I want it to:

```
# A vars file:
my_default_values:
  key = value

my_values:
  my_key = my_value


# In a playbook, I create a task to attempt merging the
# two dictionaries (which doesn't work):

- debug: msg="{{ item.key }} = {{ item.value }}"
  with_dict: my_default_values + my_values

# I have also tried:

- debug: msg="{{ item.key }} = {{ item.value }}"
  with_dict: my_default_values|union(my_values)

# I have /some/ success with using j2's update,
# but you can't use j2 syntax in "with_dict", it appears.
# This works:

- debug: msg="{{ my_default_values.update(my_values) }}"

# But this doesn't:

- debug: msg="{{ item.key }} = {{ item.value }}"
  with_dict: my_default_values.update(my_values)
```

Is there a way to merge two dictionaries, so I can use it with "with_dict"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ansible. override single dictionary key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25129728/ansible-override-single-dictionary-key)

Answer (score 105, accepted):

In Ansible 2.0, there is a Jinja filter, [`combine`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#combining-hashes-dictionaries), for this:

```
- debug: msg="{{ item.key }} = {{ item.value }}"
  with_dict: "{{ my_default_values | combine(my_values) }}"
```

Comment: Would you happen to know how to apply `combine` to a role parameter as http://stackoverflow.com/a/25131711/107158 describes?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41247778/in-ansible-how-can-i-combine-a-default-dictionary-in-a-role-with-a-dictionary-p addresses this question.

Answer (score 22):

It is now possible to use the anchor and extend features of YAML:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    my_default_values: &def
      key: value
    my_values:
      <<: *def
      my_key: my_value
  tasks:
    - debug: var=my_default_values
    - debug: var=my_values
```

Result:

```
TASK [debug]
ok: [localhost] => {
    "my_default_values": {
        "key": "value"
    }
}

TASK [debug] 
ok: [localhost] => {
    "my_values": {
        "key": "value", 
        "my_key": "my_value"
    }
}
```

I have no idea why this was not mentioned before.

Comment: That's pretty cool! While this can accomplish the task, I think the issue is that you need to decorate all the source objects with the "&name", which could be overly burdensome. This can be an issue if you are using a shared role, where the role (and original variable object) is maintained by someone else. Also, I haven't tested it, but it seems like there COULD be runtime issues with it, where the evaluation happens on file load, wheres a Jinja template solution might happen at the expected time, especially if there is a "when" modifier. Any thoughts on eval time between this and combine()?

Comment: This doesn't help when we define defaults at group level and reuse at sub-group level

Answer (score 14):

If you want hash merging I would turn the hash merging feature on in ansible. 
In your ansible config file [turn hash merging on](http://docs.ansible.com/intro_configuration.html#hash-behaviour).

With *hash_behaviour=merge* you can have two var files with the same variable name:

defaults.yml:

```
values:
  key: value
```

overrides.yml:

```
values:
  my_key: my_value
```

In order for the two vars to be merged you will need to include both var files:

```
ansible-playbook some-play.yml ... -e@defaults.yml  -e@overrides.yml
```

And you will end up with this:

```
TASK: [debug var=values] ********************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "values": {
        "key": value,
        "my_key": my_value
    }
}
```

Calling update on a variable can be done in Jinja but in general it will be messy, I wouldn't do it outside of your templates and even then try to avoid it altogether.

Comment: Changing this setting may break other roles.  Try jinja2 combine method instead.

Comment: Following on what @kalu said - Using hash merging is dangerous discouraged.

Answer (score 6):

If you need the merged dictionary a few times, you can set it to a new "variable":

```
- set_fact: _my_values="{{ my_default_values|combine(my_values) }}"

- debug: msg="{{ item.key }} = {{ item.value }}"
  with_dict: _my_values
```

Answer (score 2):

Try [this role](https://galaxy.ansible.com/eugene0707/merge_custom_vars/) from Ansible Galaxy.

I did it some time ago for same reason. It can deep merge dictionaries from several vars files and set custom precedence of merging.

This role can work under Ansible 2.0+

Answer (score -4):

```
>>> key = 'default key'
>>> value = 'default value'
>>> my_key = 'my key'
>>> my_value = 'my value'
>>>
>>> my_default_values = {key: value}
>>> print my_default_values
{'default key': 'default value'}
>>>
>>> my_values = {my_key: my_value}
>>> print my_values
{'my key': 'my value'}
>>>
>>> with_dict = my_default_value.copy()
>>> print with_dict
{'default key': 'default value'}
>>> with_dict.update(my_values)
>>> print with_dict
{'default key': 'default value', 'my key': 'my value'}
```

Comment: Right, that's what I was using in my last example. That doesn't work in ansible, or so it seems.