# Ansible, default variable

Tags: ansible

I am creating a new role. In the default directory of role I created main.yml with below content

```
asterisk:
  install: yes
  branch: 16
  user: pbx
  group: pbx
  srcdir: /usr/src/asterisk/
  url: "http://downloads.asterisk.org/pub/telephony/asterisk/asterisk-{{ asterisk.branch }}-current.tar.gz"
  url_sounds: http://downloads.asterisk.org/pub/telephony/sounds/asterisk-core-sounds-en-ulaw-current.tar.gz
  path_sound: /var/lib/asterisk/sounds/en
  mysql_support: no
```

Then in host_vars I create hostname.yml file which defined specific variables for this hosts with belowed content

```
asterisk:
  install: no
```

Ansible show to me error that aterisk.mysql_support is not defined. So question is, how to properly use defaults variables ?

Answer (score 0):

In roles you can define the common variables in the main.yml file which will be sourced by default. All non common variables you can define in their respective yml file

Comment: ok, i defined defaults variables in role/default/main.yml but i want customize one field in asterisk variable so i put changes into host_vars/asterisk.yml and this overwrite whole fields

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25422771/merging-dictionaries-in-ansible
try the above solution.

Answer (score 0):

In your `defaults`, you are defining an `asterisk` variable containing a structure with various key/value pairs inside. In `host_vars` you define a new value for that variable. It is `asterisk` as a whole that is replaced, not just the `install` property it contains. As a consequence, if you have tasks that use the other properties within `asterisk` without checking that they are defined first, they will fail.

So it is important when defining default values in a role to structure them in a way that makes using them easy. Is it coherent, even suitable, to force playbooks that use the role to redefine `asterisk` as a whole when they do not use the default value? If so, your current design is good. Otherwise, you may want to split it as define several distinct variables.

One thing that may also happen in your case (but it'd be necessary to see the tasks in the role to be sure of that), is that you do not care about the values in the other properties held by `asterisk` when `install = no`, because in that case these operations should *not* be performed. Make sure if that is not already the case that you use `when: asterisk.install` for these tasks (I think `name` may be evaluated even when the task is not to be executed, so beware). You could even put all the tasks to be executed when the value is `yes` in a separate tasks file that is conditionally included/imported.