# Combine two ansible dictionaries by common value in key

Tags: python, ansible

I have two ansible facts, one that looks like this:

```
"ansible_facts": "int_table" {
    "[{ "connection": "notconnected",
        "port": "eth1"},
      { "connection": "connected",
        "port": "eth2"}]"
```

and

```
"ansible_facts": "mac_table" {
    "[{ "mac_address": "0000.c200.0101",
        "port": "eth1"},
      { "mac_address": "0320.c500.0201",
        "port": "eth2"}]"
```

I want to create a new fact that would combine the two by their port, so that it would output

```
"ansible_facts": "new_table" {
    "[{ "mac_address": "0000.c200.0101",
        "connection": "notconnected",
        "port": "eth1"},
      { "mac_address": "0320.c500.0201",
        "connection": "connected",
        "port": "eth2"}]"
```

Is this possible with pure ansible? I've tried passing both to a custom filter to use python to combine the two but can't seem to pass two facts to the same filter.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25422771/merging-dictionaries-in-ansible) help ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is how to do it:

1. get the list of ports from 1 variable, say the `int_table`, they should be unique ports (i.e only one element in eaach list can have eth1, eth2, etc)
2. for each of these ports, find the element from `int_table` and combine it with the respective from `mac_table`
3. print the final list variable

playbook:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    int_table:
    - connection: notconnected
      port: eth1
    - connection: connected
      port: eth2
    mac_table:
    - mac_address: 0000.c200.0101
      port: eth1
    - mac_address: 0320.c500.0201
      port: eth2


  tasks:

  - name: populate merged list
    set_fact: 
      final_var: "{{ final_var | default([]) + [int_table | selectattr('port','equalto', item) | first | combine(mac_table | selectattr('port','equalto', item) | first)] }}"
    with_items: 
    - "{{ int_table | map(attribute='port') | list }}"

  - name: print merged list
    debug:
      var: final_var
```

sample output:

```
[http_offline@greenhat-29 tests]$ ansible-playbook test.yml 

PLAY [localhost] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [populate merged list] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=eth1)
ok: [localhost] => (item=eth2)

TASK [print merged list] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "final_var": [
        {
            "connection": "notconnected",
            "mac_address": "0000.c200.0101",
            "port": "eth1"
        },
        {
            "connection": "connected",
            "mac_address": "0320.c500.0201",
            "port": "eth2"
        }
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   

[http_offline@greenhat-29 tests]$
```

hope it helps