# Templating YAML with ansible

Tags: yaml, ansible, jinja2

I need to template a [configuration file](https://github.com/TracksApp/tracks/blob/master/config/database.yml.tmpl), which itself has YAML format. What is a good practice to do it?

Final file looks like this:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: tracks
  # set this if you are storing utf8 in your mysql database to handle strings
  # like "Réné". Not needed for sqlite. For PostgreSQL use encoding: unicode
  # encoding: utf8
  host: localhost
  username: root
  password: qwerty
```

Most of these variables should be defined and some need non-default values. And it's YAML both in vars and in the template. So I have to repeat almost the same structure at least twice: in the template and in the vars file.

A real problem is with the optional parameters. To set the right encoding (or none) I have to write something like:

```
# tasks/configure.yml
- include: {tracks_database}.yml

# variables/mysql2.yml
tracks_database_encoding: utf8

# templates/site.yml
development:
  database: "{{ tracks_database }}"
  {% if tracks_database_use_utf8 %}
  encoding: "{{ tracks_database_encoding }}"
  {% endif %}
```

- This looks quite ugly and breaks the YAML formatting.
- Lots of repeated code

So I've considered another way: to store the configuration as it is in a variable and just write it to the config [through a jijna filter](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_filters.html#filters-for-formatting-data).

```
# group_vars/tracks.yml
tracks_database_settings:
  development:
    name: tracks
    adapter: mysql2
    host: localhost
    encoding: utf8
    username: root
    password: qwerty

# templates/site.yml
{{ tracks_database_settings | to_nice_yaml }}
```

But there are negative effects:

- Comments are lost
- If I need to override just several variables, I have to copy the whole structure. ([`hash_behaviour=merge`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25129728/2790048) is not an option).
- Can not preset variables for different db types and `include` them.
- Elements in the dictionary get rearranged (sorted).

Is there any better way of templating YAML files? The perfect solution would be something like:

```
{{ tracks_database_default_settings_with_comments |
  with overriden values from group_vars/host_vars/whatever |
  with preset values from db-specific file |
  to_nice_yaml_with_comments }}
```

I'm currently looking at [combining hashes/dictionaries](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_filters.html#combining-hashes-dictionaries), but I still have no idea how/where to define the combined dictionaries.

---

UPD: by now I managed to do this:

```
{{ tracks_database_defaults | combine(tracks_database_override, recursive=True) | to_nice_yaml }}
```

But it looks really unusual for ansible. And still inconvenient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to current variable management behavior and your requirements:

- hash_behaviour=merge is not an option
- don't repeat yourself inside var and template files

You picked the best option.

Also, note that [combine(..., recursive=True)](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/6787fc70a643fb6e2bdd2c6a6202072d21db72ef/lib/ansible/plugins/filter/core.py#L278) filter and [hash_behaviour=merge](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/utils/vars.py#L58) use the same [merge_hash](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/utils/vars.py#L73) function.
So, it will simply replace nested scalars or arrays.