# In Ansible, how can I combine a default dictionary in a role with a dictionary passed to that role as an argument?

Tags: dictionary, ansible, jinja2, template-engine

In [Ansible](https://www.ansible.com/get-started), how can I [combine](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_filters.html#combining-hashes-dictionaries) a default dictionary in a role with a dictionary passed to that role as an argument?

Comment: I think this question doesn't deserve the down-vote. While the question didn't actually have a problem, I think it is still a useful and complete example of how a template can combine the default dictionary in a role with a dictionary passed to that role as a role parameter.

Comment: I've moved the example in the original question to an answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As a solution by example, consider role `nginx-reverse-proxy`:

*nginx-reverse-proxy/defaults/main.yml*:

```
default_nginx:
  application_context: /{{ application_name }}-{{ application_component_name }}
  reverse_proxy:
    port: 8080
```

*nginx-reverse-proxy/templates/reverse-proxy.conf*:

```
{% set combined_nginx = default_nginx | combine(nginx, recursive=true) -%}
location {{ combined_nginx.application_context }} {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:{{ combined_nginx.reverse_proxy.port }};
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

*my-nginx-reverse-proxy-meta/main.yml*:

```
dependencies:
  - selfcertification-service
  - role: nginx-reverse-proxy
    nginx: { reverse_proxy: { port: 8095 } }
```

Comment: you can also add a step in your playbook to explicitely define it for the entire play : 
```- set_fact: 
        combined_nginx: "{{ default_nginx | combine(nginx, recursive=true) }}
```