# ansible with dictionary based defaults variables

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-template

I have some default variables in my Ansible role

```
sysproperties:
 java_awt_headless:
   key: "java.awt.headless"
   value: "true"
   enabled: "true"
 java_iccprofile_path:
   key: "java.iccprofile.path"
   value: "image/iccprofiles"
   enabled: "true"
...
...
```

And they should end up in a XML file, based on a jinja2 template

```
{% for key, value in sysproperties.items() %}
<sysproperty key="{{ value.key }}" value="{{ value.value }}" enabled="{{ value.enabled }}"/>
{% endfor %}
```

To change one of the defaults, I actually wish it could be as easy as this:

```
---
- name: run this
  hosts: myTestHost
  vars:
     sysproperties.java_iccprofile_path.value: "somewhere/else"
  roles:
    - role: myRole
```

But so far, I just found that I would need an extra task, just to change this setting

```
  pre_tasks:
    - set_fact:
        sysproperties: "{{ sysproperties | combine(new_item, recursive=true) }}"
      vars:
        new_item: "{ 'java_iccprofile_path': { 'value': 'somewhere/else' } }"
      with_dict: "{{ sysproperties }}"
```

So my questions is: Is there a simpler way to this? Should I maybe arrange my defaults a bit different, so they are easier to change?

[EDIT] 
To make more clear what my actual question is:

I store settings in a list/dictionary to write them via template module to a XML file. 
I like anyone that are using my role to be able to change or add settings easily. What would be a best practice way to do so? Is the way I do it now with running a pre_task the right way or are there better ways to do this?

Answer (score 1):

One of the things you can do is to override the variable when invoking the role.  You can do this in your playbook:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  roles:
    - {role: "myRole", sysproperties.java_iccprofile_path.value: "somwhere/else"}
...
```

Hope this helps.

UPDATE
Hmm.  Interesting.  Here is my test setup:

```
myRole
+ tasks
| + main.yml
+ vars
| + main.yml
+ testrole.yml
```

Here is the content of myRole/tasks/main.yml

```
---
- name: Debugging
  debug: var=foo
...
```

Here is the content of myRole/vars/main.yml

```
---
foo: "blah"
...
```

Here is the content of testrole.yml

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  roles:
    - myRole
...
```

If I run

```
ansible-playbook ./testrole.yml
```

I get

```
PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [defaults : Debugging] ****************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "foo": "blah"
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

If I update testrole.yml to the following:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  roles:
    - {role: "myRole", foo: "yuck"}
...
```

I get

```
PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [defaults : Debugging] ****************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "foo": "yuck"
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

So, I tried with a dictionary.

myRole/vars/main.yml:

```
---
sysproperties:
  java_something_else:
    key: "path"
  java_iccprofile_path:
    value: "i/am/here"
...
```

If I put sysproperties.java_iccprofile_path.value: "some/where/else" into testrole.yml, it fails.  If I have the following in testrole.yml, it kind of works:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  roles:
    - {role: "myRole", sysproperties: {java_iccprofile_path: {value: "yuck"}}}
...
```

The output of the above is

```
PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [defaults : Debugging] ****************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "sysproperties": {
        "java_iccprofile_path": {
            "value": "yuck"
        }
    }
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

As you can see, it replaced the value, but it also deleted the other values.

I found out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25129728/ansible-override-single-dictionary-key), that changing the value of hash_behavior to merge in the ansible.cfg file will keep the old stuff and only overwrite what you told it to overwrite.

```
PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [defaults : Debugging] ****************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "sysproperties": {
        "java_iccprofile_path": {
            "value": "yuck"
        }, 
        "java_something_else": {
            "key": "path"
        }
    }
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Comment: Nope, If I do it like this, still the default value is used.

Comment: Thanks for the extensive testing! But I don't want to change ansible standard behaviour for my role. It works right now fine with this pre_tasks in the playbook. 
Actually I like to know if there is maybe a different or other best practice way to do what I like. My problem is that I have a list of settings I like to have in my template and whoever uses this role should be able to easily adapt and change such settings.

Comment: My first thought is don't use dictionaries.  If you just have simple key/value pairs, what I had originally works without having to modify the ansible.cfg file.

Comment: If I would put all my sysproperties to key/value variables, how could I then do something like this: 

```{% for key, value in sysproperties.items() %}
<sysproperty key="{{ value.key }}" value="{{ value.value }}" enabled="{{ value.enabled }}"/>
{% endfor %}```
and also add/remove sysproperties? For now I think how I do it now is the only way to go ...