# Overriding one variable in a dictionary

Tags: dictionary, ansible

*Preamble*: I realise that the question [Ansible. override single dictionary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25129728/ansible-override-single-dictionary-key) is very similar, but it is not the same and none of the answers there answer my specific question or are applicable in my use-case.

I am trying to install Dataverse, which has provided an ansible role (https://github.com/IQSS/dataverse-ansible). I am using it along multiple other roles.

There are variables in `roles/dataverse-ansible/defaults/main.yml` like:

```
dataverse:                                                                                                                              
  adminpass: admin1                                                                                                                     
  allow_signups: true                                                                                                                   
  glassfish:
    user: payara
    logformat: ulf
    siteurl:
```

From the above, I would like to only redefine `dataverse.glassfish.siteurl`. So I tried to insert into my `group_vars/all`:

```
 dataverse.glassfish.siteurl: "my_site_address"
```

However, this left `dataverse.glassfish.siteurl` empty.

From the above question, I discovered that I can state the following in my `group_vars/all`

```
dataverse:                                                                                                                              
  glassfish:                                                                                                                            
    siteurl: "my_site_address"
```

And state `hash_behaviour=merge` in my `ansible.cfg`, and it works, but this practice seems frowned upon.

**My question is**: what is the *preferred* way of overriding such variables. I do *not* want to change the upstream role code, if at all possible, so please do not say to redefine the `roles/dataverse-ansible/defaults/main.yml` to have `siteurl: {{user_defined_site_url}}` in it.

Answer (score 1):

```yaml
- set_fact:
    dataverse: >-
       {%- set _ = dataverse.glassfish.update({
           "siteurl": user_defined_site_url}) -%}
       {{ dataverse }}
```

where the `set _ =` part is because ansible evidently has disabled the [`do`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#expression-statement) verb, thus assigning to nothing is the only way to have an action with a side-effect in a jinja2 template

Comment: Ugh... If this is the preferred way, I may want to go with the frowned upon hash_behaviour=merge...

Comment: And you're welcome to do so; for your consideration, a global change like that affects all interactions with vars, whereas this affects the one task